# How to obtain benchmark data (TPC-H)

Tags: database, performance, validation, benchmarking, tpc

I have read at several places that it is always good to verify your code against benchmark data.

My question is how and from where to obtain benchmark data?

I am in need of TPC-H benchmark data and also visited http://www.tpc.org/tpch/, but could not understand how to obtain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for following link to download the [TPC_Benchmark_Tool](http://www.tpc.org/tpc_documents_current_versions/download_programs/tools-download-request.asp?bm=tpc-ds).

You have to register and agree to the licensing terms, then download link will be sent to you email address.